# Is it true the Ari said that if there is hate of one scholar to another it's because they're from the same shoresh?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, soul, arizal

Is it true that the Ari said that if there is hate from two talmidei chachamim this is because they're from the same shoresh neshama?